# To check SetFilePointerEx, ReadFile or WriteFile for success do I need to check lpNewFilePointer, lpNumberOfBytesRead and lpNumberOfBytesWritten?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm somewhat puzzled by SetFilePointerEx, ReadFile and WriteFile APIs. Say, if I want to move file pointer to a new position, is it sufficient to do:

```
if(SetFilePointerEx(hFile, liPtr, NULL, FILE_BEGIN))
{
    //Success, moved file pointer to liPtr position
}
```

Or, do I need to check the value returned in `lpNewFilePointer` too, as such?

```
LARGE_INTEGER liSetTo = {0};
if(SetFilePointerEx(hFile, liPtr, &liSetTo, FILE_BEGIN) &&
    liPtr.QuadPart == liSetTo.QuadPart)
{
    //Success
}
```

The same applies to ReadFile and WriteFile. For instance:

```
if(WriteFile(hFile, buffer, numberBytesToWrite, NULL, NULL))
{
    //Success writing numberBytesToWrite into file
}
```

Or do I need to do this to make sure that all my data was written successfully:

```
DWORD numberBytesWritten = 0;
if(WriteFile(hFile, buffer, numberBytesToWrite, &numberBytesWritten, NULL) &&
    numberBytesWritten == numberBytesToWrite)
{
    //Success writing numberBytesToWrite into file
}
```

In other words, what's the point to have those return sizes and offsets? I mean, if I want it to write 1024 bytes into a file, can it just write 1000 instead. :) If it doesn't write all the data that I requested it to, wouldn't it constitute an error, or `FALSE` to be returned from the API?

Anyway, I'd appreciate if someone could clarify.

Comment: setpointer returns the new position from the beginning of the file. As for read/write, yes, they can return success, but read/write less bytes you've specified.

Comment: @geza: At what circumstances would, say, `WriteFile` return `TRUE` and `numberBytesToWrite` != `numberBytesWritten` in my example?

Comment: One instance where WriteFile won't write the requested amount when the disk gets full (or the user's storage quota is reached).  ReadFile will read less when reaching the end of the file.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm: Yeah, but wouldn't the API itself return `FALSE` in that case?

Comment: One example is that a ReadFile from a named pipe will return at the end of the corresponding write operation.  So if you asked for 10 bytes but the process at the other end of the pipe only send 5, you'll only get 5.  Also, non-blocking sockets may read and/or write fewer bytes than requested.  I don't *think* writing to an ordinary file will ever write fewer bytes than requested.

Comment: for `ReadFile` - it can return `true` but less bytes than you request - if file containing less bytes (from read position to the end). about `WriteFile` - I never view this situation for filesystem files, but theoretical this can be for some files on some device. about `SetFilePointerEx` - for my look this is absolute senseless api - i don't know any situation where it really needed

Comment: @RbMm: It's not senseless. For example, if you use FILE_CURRENT, you specify delta position, and you'll get absolute position back. But yes, in the case of FILE_BEGIN, there's no reason for returning the absolute position. In this case, just give a NULL parameter for that.

Comment: @geza - `you'll get absolute position back` - and for what this position ?

Comment: Read/write could read/write less than you specified for some reasons, even for files. I'm not saying that they do happen, but the API allows them to happen. You should be on the safe side, and handle these situations. For example, in case of full disk, or full quota, WriteFile may return less. Or, if a file is on a network drive, a ReadFile may return less than you requested (I'm not saying that this happens, but it could).

Comment: @RbMm: sorry, I don't understand what you're asking

Comment: @geza - i mean that *CurrentByteOffset* (or how you say absolute position) - almost useless information - for what/how use it ? however for query it the best use [`ZwQueryInformationFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567052(v=vs.85).aspx) with `FilePositionInformation`

Comment: @RbMm: you can use SetFilePointerEx for querying the actual file position (FILE_CURRENT with 0 delta). Yes, questionable design, but I wouldn't call it senseless. But I'd definitely use this solution instead of Zw*/Nt* functions in user mode code for querying the actual file position.

Comment: Here's a related question about this subject, but in the unix world (same principles, just different function name): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964806/short-read-from-filesystem-when-can-it-happen

Comment: @geza -  Zw*/Nt* worked in user mode also and have 1 query data more native than make query + set. but task not in this. assume you got `CurrentByteOffset` and what next ? how use it ? for what this knowledge need at all ?

Comment: I'm not saying they don't work. They are low-level functions. They don't return HRESULT, but NTSTATUS. They are only available from win2000 (this doesn't matter too much, I know). Why would I use them for querying filepos? I'm sorry, I don't understand your question. You question filepos query function usefulness, or what? With `SetFilePointerEx`, you can set and/or get filepos. As I've said, it is questionable design, but not senseless. If at a certain point of your program, you need to setpos, and you don't need the resulting filepos, then pass NULL to that parameter.

Comment: @RbMm: The Zw*/Nt* functions aren't part of the Windows API. No explicit contract has been published as to the availability. They can get removed in a future version (unlikely), have additional restrictions applied (e.g. can only be called from signed binaries), or get blocked by security software unless called from trusted system modules.

Comment: @IInspectable - i primary say about useless information about `CurrentByteOffset` for file handle. about Zw*/Nt* this is separate question

Comment: @RbMm: That's still useful information. Consider code that parses a structured binary file, where headers store header-relative offsets to data. A function that parses a specific header to return the absolute offsets to data will want to know about the current file position.

Comment: @IInspectable - this all of course off-topic for main question - but i not view in your example for what here need know current offset in file handle. when we need read or write at concrete byte offset - so and need do this by set explicit offset in read or write operation. knowledge of current byte offset not need here

Comment: @RbMm: This is anything but off-topic, since the question is asking about the utility of `SetFilePointerEx`, and you claim, that it's useless. Anyway, here it goes again: If you need the absolute file offset of data in a file, that only stores offsets relative to the current file position, you obviously need to query the current file position. Or consider a PDF file, where you need to record the current file position whenever you write out an object header, so that you can construct the final `xref` directory. Querying the current file position *is* useful.

Comment: @IInspectable - usual, when i write or read to file - i know position to which(from which) i write(read). however if not mantain it yourself,but query for this exist `ZwQueryInformationFile` with `FilePositionInformation`. very strange (from my look) *set* postion too, when we need exactly query only. and not need say that `ZwQueryInformationFile` undocumented - very well documented and always was, not design for user mode (design, and about this direct note in msdn) etc

Comment: @RbMm: This question is tagged [tag:winapi]. `ZwQueryInformationFile` is not part of the Windows API. No one claimed, that it wasn't documented either. Please exercise more diligence when responding to comments. As for your suggestion to maintain a shadow copy of the current file position: Storing redundant state is probably *the* most successful way to write unmaintainable code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `SetFilePointerEx`, you should only check it's return value. It contains whether the operation was a SUCCESS.

For a synchronous `ReadFile`/`WriteFile`, if it returns false, then the operation has completely failed (no bytes read/written at all). If it returns true, then you should check `lpNumberOfBytesRead`/ `lpNumberOfBytesWritten`, as it can be lower then the number you specified. For example, for read, if EOF reached, then you'll get a short read. For write, if disk becomes full during write, you may get a short write.

There could be other various reasons for short read/write, so your code should handle these cases.

Comment: _For ReadFile/WriteFile, if it returns false, then the operation has completely failed_ ... read the docs more carefully: _If the function fails, or is completing **asynchronously**, the return value is zero (FALSE)._

Comment: @zett42: added "synchronous"

Comment: @zett42 - the very formulation of the question implicit assume synchronous operation. in case asynchronous io (when pending returned) the NumberOfBytesRead is undefined (yet not filled). and for synchronous io answer is correct

Comment: If the disk is full, the write will fail - it won't do a partial write.  (Not on NTFS, at any rate - I've just checked.)

Comment: (That's just a nitpick, mind you, I agree that you should always check whether the expected number of bytes were read or written.  +1.  I would generally treat a short write as an error condition.)